# Create JSONObject inside JSONObject to post the data

Tags: java, android, json

I would like to create below JSON for the post in the body. I would like to build this JSON using the native class.

```
[
  {
    "message": {
      "data": "E-Stop Off"
    },
    "platform": "ros",
    "topic": "/android_app/nav_control",
    "type": "std_msgs/String",
    "expiration_secs": 1
    
  }
]
```

I am using this method more often with few changes that is why I pass the argument in the method. I am not able to add JSONObject inside JSONObject. Here is my effort.

```
 public String postCommandJSON(JSONObject jsonObject, String topic, String type) {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        try {
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();

            mainObject.put("platform", "ros");
            mainObject.put("topic", topic);
            mainObject.put("type", type);
            mainObject.put("expiration_secs", 1);

            mainObject.put(jsonObject);
            jsonArray.put(mainObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return jsonArray.toString();
    }
```

I am not able to add JSONObject inside JSONObject in below line.

> mainObject.put(jsonObject);

Thank you

Comment: "*When I add Object inside object I got an error.*" I am not Android dev so I may be wrong, but usually information *about* error in question (like error message, stacktrace, comparison between expected vs actual result) is very helpful while solving problems. So to *possibly* increase chances of getting proper answer consider adding more *specific* details about problem you are facing.

Comment: Read the error message, search for it on Google, and look at the hints given to you by your IDE. You should be able to figure out what the problem is from that. Also, if you are going to post a question here asking about help with an error/exception, you need to include the error details as well.

Comment: For now all I can *guess* is that you missed content of *key* part while passing only content of *value* into an JSON object (since JSON objects store key->value pairs). Probably `put` method expects `key` and `value` but at `mainObject.put(jsonObject);` you place only *value* without specifying any key (which here based on example should be `"message"`)

Comment: What is the error that you get on that line?

Comment: @ArpitPatel [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) != [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject), and they do not have the same methods.

Comment: @ArpitPatel "*but we can also add an object in put() method*" are you sure? I am guessing that you may be confusing arrays `[]` with objects `{}`. Usually when we `put` element to array it will be placed at the end so array will implicitly assign proper index to that value, but in case of objects keys should be explicitly specified.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how should I get that JSON? And Yes I know the difference between JSONArray and Object.

Comment: Based on your example I would guess you may be looking for code like `mainObject.put("message", jsonObject);`. Also may you want to execute it before `mainObject.put("platform", "ros");` (assuming order of key-value pairs is important and depend on order of executing `put` method on a JSON object).

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: That is the answer of my question

Comment: Glad I could help, but could you [edit] your question and include exact copy of error message you ware getting for this problem? Otherwise people facing same problem may not be able to find your question and potential answer to their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that at `mainObject.put(jsonObject);` you attempt to crate something along

```
{
    "message": {
      "data": "E-Stop Off"
    }
    ...
}
```

then beside value (which will be JSON object) you also need to pass to `put` method a `key` via which we will later be able to access that value.

So you probably want to change that line into

```
mainObject.put("message", jsonObject);
```

and maybe even execute it before `mainObject.put("platform", "ros");` if order of elements is important.

Comment: Does it matter that when I am adding object ?

Comment: That depends on JSON library you are using. Some of them don't preserve insertion order but some do (like I said I am not Android dev and can't test it, but may guess is it may preserve it).

Comment: Okay I will add them in order

Comment: Thank You @Pshemo for your help look like you are an expert in programming.